# Метод onConfigurationChanged() не вызывается при изменении Локали

Tags: android, locale, context, multilanguage

Я хочу реализовать возможность переключения языка в синглАктивити-приложении.
Как я понял, при изменении Локали (Local) должен вызываться метод onConfigurationChanged, в нем я планировал вызвать recreate у Активити, но судя по логам вызов не происходит.

Вот манифест приложения:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.activities.main.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale|orientation|screenSize"
>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!--     filter for DeepLink handling       -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data
                    android:host="@string/app_host_main"
                    android:scheme="@string/app_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Приложение поддерживает направление текста справа налево (`android:supportsRtl="true"`)

И собственно кусок кода из Activity, локаль по умолчанию стоит русская, я ее прямо в onCreate меняю на английскую

```
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        installSplashScreen()

        setContentView(viewBinding.root)

        // Setting up start destination
        defineStartDestination()

        setupBottomNavigationView()

        val config = Configuration(this.resources.configuration)
        val locale = Locale("en")
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            config.setLocale(locale)
            Log.d("Kty", "am1")
        } else {
            config.locale = locale
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            this.createConfigurationContext(config)
            this.resources.updateConfiguration(config, this.resources.displayMetrics)
            Log.d("Kty", "am2")
        }
        config.setLocale(locale)
        config.setLayoutDirection(locale)
        this.createConfigurationContext(config)
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        Log.d("Kty", "Conf changed")
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        Log.d("Kty", "Conf changed")
    }
```

В логах я вижу "am1", "am2", но не "Conf changed". Приложение отображается на английском, т е локаль меняется, но onConfigurationChanged() не вызывается. Я хочу понять почему. Значит ли это что onConfigurationChanged() вызывается только при изменении настроек устройства, но не приложения ? В документации-исходниках есть фраза Called by the system when the device configuration changes while your activity is running. Или я делаю что-то не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут [написано](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config) о `locale`

> The locale has changed — the user has selected a new language that text should be displayed in.

Стоит понимать что программные смены локали не засчитываются, о них вы и так знаете.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я примерно так себе и представлял.